# Error en MySQL al iniciar

Tags: mysql

Espero se encuentre alguien que ya haya pasado por este error.

```
2022-06-04 21:02:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2022-06-04 21:02:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2022-06-04 21:02:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2022-06-04 21:02:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2022-06-04 21:02:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2022-06-04 21:02:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2022-06-04 21:02:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-06-04 21:02:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2022-06-04 21:02:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2022-06-04 21:02:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2022-06-04 21:02:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2022-06-04 21:02:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2022-06-04 21:02:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.17 started; log sequence number 30885481; transaction id 10365
2022-06-04 21:02:41 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-06-04 21:02:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2022-06-04 21:02:41 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

No he desinstalado, ya cambie el puerto por 8080 en el archivo httpd.conf / httpd-ssl.conf LISTEN 4433 y en my.cnf

```
# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client]
# password       = your_password 
port=3307
socket="C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"

# Here follows entries for some specific programs 

# The MySQL server
default-character-set=utf8mb4
[mysqld]
port=3307
```

Y sigue sin funcionar, saludos.